# Derivative is a Radon measure if time increment bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

[image]

Here, $u$ belongs to some $L^p$ space. Can someone tell me what result the author uses to say that $u_t$ is a Radon measure?

Comment: Presumably, the Riesz representation theorem: if a functional is bounded by the supremum norm of a continuous function, it's a Radon measure. But I can't say more without knowing what $u_0$ is, how it relates to $u$, etc.